# openlayer select wms layer

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

in my application I have a googlemap and some WMS layers coming from geoserver, I need to select the features on these layers, I followed this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeature-wfs.html, I get no errors, when I click on a feature, the mouse start to spin, but with no result at all, this is my code:

```
var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Hybrid",
        {"type": google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20}
    );
            var options = {
            controls: [],
            //sphericalMercator:true,
            //projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913'), // senza la proiezione mi stampa metà layer
            units: "m",
            numZoomLevels: 22,            
            maxResolution: 156543.0339,
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34,
                         20037508.34, 20037508.34)
            };
            var panZoom = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom();
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
                div: "gmap",
                projection: "EPSG:900913",
                displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
                //zoomOffset: 5
        controls: [
            panZoom,
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
        ]
        });
var regioni      = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "regioni",
            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
            {
            layers: "metmi-italy:reg2011_g" ,
            transparent: "true",
            format: "image/png",
            srs:'EPSG:900913', // old: 'EPSG:2077'
            //zoomOffset: 4,
            },
            {isBaseLayer: false,}
        );
control = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
        protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(regioni),
        box: true,
        hover: true,
        multipleKey: "shiftKey",
        toggleKey: "ctrlKey"
        });
select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selezioni", {styleMap: 
        new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"])
        });
map.addLayers([ghyb,regioni,select])
control.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) {
            removeFeaturesFromGrid(e.feature.fid);
        select.removeFeatures([e.feature]);

        });
control.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
                console.log('selected')
                select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
                //addFeaturesToGrid(e.feature);         
        });
map.addControl(control);
control.activate()
```

I think there is something that is missing, but I do not find it

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the GetFeature class, but I use WMSGetFeatureInfo in this case.

```
    var clickControl = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
            title: 'Some title',
            layers: [regioni],
            queryVisible: true,
            infoFormat: 'application/vnd.ogc.gml',
            maxFeatures: 10
    });
```

As to general steps to debug, I would encourage you to use your tools to figure out what, if any, HTTP request is being made by your browser.  If using Chrome or Safari, you can right click, "Inspect Element", go to the network tab, and then click the map.  A request should show in the network tab and you can diagnose if the request looks correct and if the response looks correct.